# How to Add Candlestick Pattern Marker on Stock Close Price Data Chart using Python's Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, candlestick-chart, yfinance

```
#Importing Libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import talib
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

#Collecting Data from Yahoo Finance

stock= 'COALINDIA.NS'
df= yf.download(stock,period='1mo', interval='1d')

#Using talib library to find instances where DOJI Candlestick Pattern showed up

doji = talib.CDLDOJI(df['Open'], df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'])
df['Doji']= doji

#Using a variable to store all instances where the DOJI Candlestick Pattern was true (i.e. value > 0)

DojiSignal=[]

for i in range(0, len(df['Doji'])):
    if df['Doji'][i] > 0:
        DojiSignal.append(df['Doji'][i])

#Plotting Close price of the stock along with the days where DOJI Candlestick Pattern showed up (i.e. was TRUE)

figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 6))
plt.plot(df['Close'], markevery= DojiSignal)
plt.show()
```

Hello,

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Pull stock data from Yahoo Finance.
2. Store the data in a dataframe (df).
3. Use the DOJI function from the talib library to perform the required task of finding whether a particular trading day had a DOJI Candle Pattern show up.
4. Then I'm trying to add all the days where the condition i.e. DOJI Pattern showed up (value !=0) in a list.
5. Finally, I want to plot a chart of 'Close Price' of the stock and also mark the days where the DOJI Candle Pattern was true using the '*' marker.

Point numbers 4 and 5 is where I believe I'm struggling.

I'd really appreciate it if you could please help me out with some explanation as to what needs to be improved?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of the python library **mplfinance** (MatPlotLib finance), and I would recommend using that library to plot signal markers on stock market data.

Here is an example plot of stock market data with signal markers:
[image]

To make a similar plot with mplfinance for your code example above:

- Set the value of the Doji signal to a price slightly less than the Low price on the day of the signal.  This causes the signal marker to appear just under the OHLC bar or Candlestick (as shown in the above example plot).
- *All non-signal values in the* `df['Doji']` *column must be set to* `float('nan')` so that no signal marker will appear on the plot for those dates.
- Pass the `df['Doji']` into the `mpf.make_addplot()` api and take its output and pass it into the `addplot` kwarg in the `mpf.plot()` api as follows:

  ```py
  mpf.make_addplot(df['Doji'])
  mpf.plot(df,addplot=ap)
  ```

You can find [basic usage here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#usage),
 and a [tutorial on how to add signal markers and other studies here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb).
  Hope that helps.